# How to create a Gemfile?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm very new to Ruby.

I was following a blog post that says that in order to install a required dependencies I need to create a Gemfile.

How do I create a Gemfile with `rspec` as a dependency?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The Gemfile is just a text file within your project which contains a list of gems for use in your application.

If you do not have one in your application, you can create the file using an editor of your choice, saving it as `Gemfile` (with no extension), and in your example, containing:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rspec'
```

Comment: I took so long to realize that all I need was to create a file named "Gemfile" with no extension. I thought I was creating a gem at this point.

Answer (score 185):

[bundle init](https://bundler.io/man/bundle-init.1.html) generates a Gemfile into the current working directory.

```sh
$ bundle init
Writing new Gemfile to /app/Gemfile

$ cat Gemfile 
# frozen_string_literal: true

source "https://rubygems.org"

git_source(:github) {|repo_name| "https://github.com/#{repo_name}" }

# gem "rails"
```

Answer (score 0):

A gemfile is automatically created when you start a new rails application.

type `rails new appName` and then it will be generated automatically. It will also be populated with some gems.

To install the gems run `bundle install` or simply `bundle`

Make sure you are requiring the gems you need. specifically `rspec` and `jruby`

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.0'
end
```

Look at this website for more information

http://bundler.io/

Comment: rails not mentioned

Comment: jruby is not a gem